# Put strings.exe command results to array / Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have code, which uses this tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings :

```
$listOfFiles=(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\test' -Include "*.dll","*.exe" -recurse | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName})

Foreach($file in $listOfFiles)
{
    strings.exe -n 10 $file >> test.txt
}
```

How can I put results from 'strings.exe -n 10 $file' command to the array?

Because later I would like to display them in my created csv table.

Comment: Do you want to keep track of which file each string comes from, or do you just need one big array of all strings extracted?

Comment: I would like to track strings from which files they come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` to create 1 new object per string output by `strings.exe`, then assign all the output from the entire loop to a single variable:

```
$listOfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\test' -Include "*.dll","*.exe" -Recurse |ForEach-Object FullName

$strings = foreach($file in $listOfFiles)
{
    strings.exe -n 10 $file |Select-Object @{Name='String';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FilePath';Expression={$file}}
}
```

Comment: The idea is great, but the problem is that each string has the same filePath. I would like to have a table with rows of one column with filePath name and another column with all strings from that file.